# How to position a background image off center?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a background image set to center and needs to be fixed position. However I would like to just nudge it 100px off center, any ideas?

CSS
     background: url(styles/images/bg.png) no-repeat center 0;
     background-attachment: fixed;

This is the working sample
http://www.warface.co.uk/clients/detail-shoppe/

Comment: Can't just edit the image? :/

Comment: I would need to add a massive clear space that's going to increase the file size. It needs to be kept in the position with the content on browser resize

Answer (score 5):

Creating a larger background image that is 300px wider (left or right respectively) will shift the background 150px from center. There is no css style in the background property that will do this. If you don't want to create more div's, this is the only way.

Comment: This solution is the only valid one, that really answer Rob's problem (I had the same...). Indeed setting a background position to 100px will move the anchor of the image.

Comment: You can perform such operation with image magick wery simply : convert image.jpg -gravity East -extend <width+300>x<height> image_extended.jpg by replacing width and height by the original dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by positioning your background something close to 50% from the left or right. If you need it a specific number of pixels left/right from the center, you will need to use `calc()` to add an offset of a different unit. For instance if you want the background shifted 100 pixels left from bein center, you'll need to use `background-position: left calc(50% - 100px)`. Pay special attention to the spacing inside the parentheses as they are mandatory. If you want there to be 100 pixels from the edge of the background image and the center line, you'll also need to subtract half the width of the background image.

---

To elaborate on this further (in case it's useful), I had two separate scenarios I was trying to solve. I was looking for how to position a background image to start at the side of a responsive element at all times without changing any HTML. The element was centered on the page at all times and changed widths depending on the screen size. The first example matches your question, which is that the element was a fixed number of pixels wide so my background image had to be half that number of pixels to the left of center in addition to half the width of the background image (this is what the first paragraph describes).

The second scenario is that the main element was 85% of the page size. This makes the margin on the left side 7.5%, but to correctly handle this you need to set `background-position` to the following: `calc(7.5% - var(--image-width) * 0.925)` (replacing `var(--image-width)` with the background image width in units of pixels and 0.925 being the difference between 1 and the decimal representation of 7.5%, or `1 - 0.075`).

Here are some examples:

```css
:root {
  /* Informational: */
  --background-width: 100px;
}
.div2 {
  width: 300px;
}
.div3 {
  width: 90%;
}
.background {
  /* Using multiple backgrounds, labeled below */
  background-position: top left calc(50% - var(--background-width) / 2),
                       top left calc(50% - var(--background-width) / 2 - 150px),
                       top left calc(5% - var(--background-width) * 0.95);
      /* Line 1: Position 50% over, then subtract half the background
                 width (100px / 2) to shift background edge from center */
      /* Line 2: Center, then subtract half the background width (100px / 2),
                 then subtract half the element width (300px / 2) to shift
                 150 pixels from background edge to center */
      /* Line 3: Position 5% over, then 5% the background width (100px * 0.95)
                 to shift background edge from 5% mark */
}

/* EVERYTHING BELOW CAN BE IGNORED. Scenario setup: */
div div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.div1 div {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
}
.div1 .left {
  text-align: right;
}
.div1 .right {
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.background {
  margin: 0 40px;
  /* Emulates background image examples: */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f77 30px, transparent 30px),
                    linear-gradient(transparent 40px, #3d3 40px, #3d3 70px, transparent 70px),
                    linear-gradient(transparent 80px, #77f 80px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--background-width) auto;
}
```

```html
All colored background boxes are applied from the parent element:
<div class="background">
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="left">Center&nbsp;</div><div class="right">&nbsp;Line</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">300px wide</div>
  <div class="div3">90% wide</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

looks like `background-position` is what you are looking for.

Check out this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) for more details

Comment: This answer is only a broken link to a w3schools page that doesn't answer the OP's question.